# PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(): Is there an equivalent Method for .Net Framework 4.6/4.x Applications?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, azure-storage

Is there an equivalent method, to the.Net Core PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage() method, which is available for .Net Framework 4.6 applications?

I have a .Net Framework 4.6 MVC app, and would like to persist the encryption key, used for cookie encryption/decryption, to an Azure container.  I've found that this can be done for .Net Core applications, but need to do the same in a .Net Framework 4.6 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no similar method available , as it 's a feature of dot net core.Though you can use Azure key vault in you web application in dot net framework 4.6.
For using azure key vault , setu, retrieve keys and setting up , you can below this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service